# Retrieve data from one MySQL table and use it in another one

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

I have two tables i use in jqgrid.

```
Table 1: id->0,1,2; state->1,1,0

Table 2: id->0,1,2,3; product->apple,banana,cherry,melon;
```

I want to find the id's which have state 1 and retrieve the corresponding product from the other table. Is there a proper way to do it?
$result below always returns zero. I am connected to the database successfully.

Here is the code:

```
$var  = "SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE state = 1";

$result = mysql_query($var);

$grid->setSelect('order', "SELECT id, product FROM table2 WHERE id='$result' ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run one query:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.product
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.id = (SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.state = 1);
```

If the subquery could conceivably return more than one result, then use `in` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.product
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.id IN (SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.state = 1);
```